# VBA Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to use vba regular expressions to find images in html code.  In the image name examples below, the pattern I have only finds the second image but not the first image.

```
.Pattern = "<img\s*src=""([^""]*)"""

<img width="100%" src="red_blue.jpg">
<img src="img7993xyz71.jpg">
```

Comment: Replace `\s*` with `.*`

Comment: @DavidStarkey I would use `.*?` for ungreedy matching.

Comment: @HamZa Yea I assumed 1 `<img>` per line and `.` is not setup to match newline.

Comment: @DavidStarkey `(?s)` modifier !

Comment: what's the point of looking for src in the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

The problem with using a `.*?` is that if the img tag doesn't have a src attribute, then you might match more text then you're interested, or you might accidentally find the src attribute of a subsequent non-img tag.

This regex will capture the entire img tag, and will pull out the src attribute value. If the img tag doesn't have an src attribute, then the img tag will be skipped.

Regex: `<img\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?>`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the second line has some difficult edge cases

```
<img width="100%" src="red_blue.jpg">
<img onmouseover=' var src="NotRealImage.png" ; funImageSwap(src); '><form><input type="image" src="submit.gif"></form>
<img src="img7993xyz71.jpg">
```

**Code**

I realize this example is vb.net and not vba, I'm only including this to show that the solution will work with the .net regex engine.

```
VB.NET Code Example:
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("<img\b(?=\s) # capture the open tag
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=('[^']*'|""[^""]*""|[^'""][^\s>]*)) # get the href attribute
(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""\s]*)*""\s?> # get the entire tag
",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = <img width="100%" src="red_blue.jpg">
[0][1] = "red_blue.jpg"
[1][0] = <img src="img7993xyz71.jpg">
[1][1] = "img7993xyz71.jpg"
```

Comment: Thank You!  your answer is very helpful, I will change my code and test it.